# SCSS: Lack of more powerful nesting

Tags: sass, css-selectors

Recently I've ended up with the following SCSS code:

```
.modal {
    ....

    button,
    .button {
        ....
    }

    input + button,
    input + .button {
        ....
    }
}
```

First that came to my head was to **simplify** it like this:

```
.modal {
    ....

    button,
    .button {
        ....

        input + & {
        ....
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I've got the following output:

```
input + .modal. button,
input + .modal .button {
   ....
}
```

instead of desired

```
.modal input + button,
.modal input + .button {
   ....
}
```

I'm asking if the complicated selector in the first listing can be simplified or not.

Comment: "CSS3(4)" Any CSS standard beyond CSS2 is CSS3. CSS4 is a misnomer, once you consider that some CSS3 modules are in fact level 1.

Comment: Selectors and combinators are linear. If you simply want a `label` that is both an adjacent sibling of `input` and a descendant of `.form`, the selector to use is `.form input + label`. I cannot comment on how to achieve this using nested rules in Sass, however :(

Comment: @BoltClock If you consider, that the naming convention comes from the level of the most common modules, which are currently in their third revision, then might be not *that* wrong. Especially if you know that the selectors module is probably the most prominent one and Level 4 already is in progress for several years now;)

Comment: @Christoph: I knew I shouldn't have brought it up at all. I think this whole leveling scheme is a mess to be honest :/

Comment: The output you're getting isn't possible.  You *should* be getting `input + .modal button, input + .modal .button` for your selector.

Comment: @cimmanon, you are right, thank you for your attention. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sass 3.3 offers a way to do it, but the cure is worse than the disease:

```
.modal {
    color: red;

    @at-root .button, button {
        color: blue;

        input + & {
            .modal & {
                color: green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also get your desired results by using extends (which is a bit cleaner, in my opinion):

```
.modal {
    color: red;

    .button, button {
        @extend %button;
    }
}

%button {
    color: blue;

    input + & {
        color: green;
    }
}
```